# Why yield StopIteration out while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I'm using `yield from`, but I don't know about the influence of `while` for `yield`. If I put `yield from` in a `while` loop, it works well, but when I cancel the loop at the mean time an exception occurs.

```py
final_result = {}
def sales_sum(pro_name):
    total = 0
    nums = []
    while True:
        x = yield
        print(pro_name+" Sales volume: ", x)
        if not x:
            break
        total += x
        nums.append(x)
    return total, nums

def middle(key):
    while True:
        final_result[key] = yield from sales_sum(key)

def middle2(key):
    final_result[key] = yield from sales_sum(key)

def main(fun):
    data_sets = { "A": [1200, 1500], "B": [28,55,98]}
    for key, data_set in data_sets.items():
        m = fun(key)
        m.send(None)
        for value in data_set:
            m.send(value)
        m.send(None)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(middle) # work well
    main(middle2) # StopIteration
```

I expect `main(middle2)` to work well as `main(middle)`, but there is a `StopIteration` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the unexpected `StopIteration` exception in `main` is that your `m.send(None)` call causes your `middle2` generator to be exhausted (after the sub-generator `sales_sum` breaks out of its loop in response to the falsey value it received). When a generator is exhausted, it raises `StopIteration`. Normally that's invisible because you consume iterators in `for` loops, but in this case, it breaks your code.

There are a few ways you could fix this. One would be to use a two-argument call to `next` instead of using `m.send(None)`:

```
next(m, None)
```

This does the same thing as `m.send(None)`, but has the added benefit of suppressing the `StopIteration`. Note that the `None` in the call to `next` is not really the same as the one in `send`. It's the default return value in the case of an exhausted iterator, not the value that gets sent in (which is always `None` when using `next`).

Another approach would be to change `middle2` so that it doesn't end when the `sales_sum` generator does. You could add an extra `yield` statement at the end, so that it yields control one last time after doing its assignment to `final_result` when its sub-generator returns.

A final idea would be to replace `m.send(None)` with `m.close()`. This would require some changes in `final_result`, as the `close` call will throw a `GeneratorExit` exception into the generator. If you expect it, you could use that as your signal to be done instead of looking for a falsey value:

```
def sales_sum(pro_name):
    total = 0
    nums = []
    while True:
        try:
            x = yield
        except GeneratorExit:
            return total, nums

        print(pro_name+" Sales volume: ", x)
        total += x
        nums.append(x)
```

With this change, `middle2` would not need any modification.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Now, i want to know more about the details of "yield from", have u some suggestions?

Comment: I suggest reading [PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/), to learn about how `yield from` and the generator `close()` method (among other things) were added to Python.

Answer (score 1):

`sales_sum` is a finite iterator. `middle2` iterates over it exactly once; `middle` tries to iterate over it multiple times.

Comment: you mean it has entered the next loop in the `middle` before the next `for` in the `main`?